# How to get login text boxes values in HTTP Module in asp.net 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, ihttpmodule

I am making a Http Module for authentication in my web application in asp.net 2.0. When the AuthticateRequest event is fired then I get the userid and password values from current request. But Every time I am getting null in both. My code is here

```
namespace Business.YouBecome
{
    class LoginModuleYouBecome : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication httpApplication)
        {
            httpApplication.AuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(httpApplication_AuthenticateRequest);
           // httpApplication.AuthorizeRequest += new EventHandler(httpApplication_AuthorizeRequest);
        }

 void httpApplication_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
            HttpContext context = (HttpContext)application.Context;

            clsLogin login = new clsLogin();
            login.UserName = application.Request["txtuser"];
            login.Password = application.Request["txtpass"];


            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
 public void Dispose() { }
    }
}
```

I have this class in a class library project and added the code in web.config.

Please suggest me where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try like this: in your event handler you should check if your user is authenticated and then use User.Identity to access name and password.

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{

  //...
  login.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
  login.Password = User.Identity.Password;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I am trying to authenticate the user here and so I want login information which is unavailable here. Every time I get null. I got reference from here. http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020417.htm

Comment: @Deepak sorry I misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted to add more logic after the regular forms authentication.